# How to write desgin in console.log?

Tags: javascript, jquery

HI now i know about `console.log` but if i create a design as like below in a single function or online tools .

I want to create a design as like this

```
****************
 * Rohit Azad * 
****************
 *************
   ********
     ***
      *
 ****   
 ** 
 ****
```

How to print this in `console.log`

if you see flipchart and check to console.log than you can see this if i create this than can i create more console.log now way it's other way to write like this

```
hey there, geek!
                                                we're so glad you
                                             found us! So do you
                                            possess a
                                            <strong>
                                           @passion@
                                   for coding? Love to build()
                                   cool stuff? Do you wanna be
                                  a part of India's *leading*
                                         *online**
                                         shopping
                                        platform?
                                        =Guess==
                                       what!!!!!
                                       We   are
                                      #hiring!!
                                      Come join
                                     the Big F
                                     and teach
                                    ==India==
                                    the  new
                                   way >> to
                                  ***shop**
                               Build   the
             country's  e-commerce   with
            your own hands! May  the 
            force be with you...
```

Comment: what about three logs?

Comment: no it's just example if i create a long sms or some desgin as like tree design and name to anything

Comment: @RohitAzad i think you should add in your question that you wanted a dynamic approach. If that is what you wanted.

Comment: This is purely dependent on your logic. And it vary from one design to another.

Comment: @guradio his question was clearly *"How to print **this** in console.log"*  (*emphasis mine*) and editing it into something else invalidates a lot of answers. One should proof read a question few times before posting it. This is not the kind of question I expect from a 20k user.. my answer was more like a troll one. His question should've been asking for algorithm for generating dynamic designs  in console...

Comment: @TJ i see what you did there :)

Comment: [ascii-art](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ascii-art)

Comment: Put the formatted text into `textarea` element, and log `value` of that element. [Like so ...](https://jsfiddle.net/8hzd77oa/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\n` character:

```
var str = "****************\n* Rohit Azad *\n****************";
console.log(str);
```

---

As per updates:

It seems very clear that you have to calculate the tabs,spaces,newlines etc to achieve that. My suggestion is to use multiline string with backticks which came in ecmascript version 6.

```
var str = `
           **********************
            *    Rohit Azad    *
           **********************
            ********************
              ***************
                  ******
                  ******
                   ****`;

console.log(str);
```

But remember this can't be used with browsers currently, you can use some transpilers to convert it to es5 code but that won't be accurate *(i guess.)*

[**Checkout this in action**](http://www.es6fiddle.net/ikqis1x7/) and look in browser's console not the embedded one.

Comment: I know about this but i m try to a function if i create a tree than

Comment: @RohitAzad hmm...That is quite interesting. but for that you need to calculate tabs, newlines etc. Or multiline string of es6 can be used.

Comment: @RohitAzad checkout the link.

Answer (score 0):

Because `\n` denotes a newline, you'd want something like

```
console.log("*****************\n * Rohit Azad *\n*****************");
```

Answer (score 0):

`%c` is used to animate. This works perfectly on chrome browser.

```
    console.log("\t\t\t\t\t%c    Developed by ~ Sumit Sahay", "color:blue; font-weight:bold");
    console.log("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tMobile Number:");
    console.log("\t\t\t\t\t%c               +xxxxxxxxxx", "color:green; font-weight:bold");
    console.log("\n\t\t\t\t%c               Kindly run on server", "color:black; font-weight:bold");
```

Answer (score -1):

1) using single console.log

```
console.log("**************** \n * Rohit Azad *  \n**************** ");
```

2) using three console.log

```
console.log("**************** \n");
```

console.log(" * Rohit Azad * \n");
   console.log("****************");